# How to Play next Song in android(MediaPlayer)?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, goto

**First of all, Here is my Code. I have Explained my problems and thoughts below :--**

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener
            (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {



                         int Current_Song;
                         Songs song = Song.get(i);

                         //If mediaPlayer is not used before, this will make oldsong as present song.
                         if (Old_Song == -326523) {
                             Old_Song = song.getSong();
                         }

                         Current_Song = song.getSong();

                         ImageView IVP_P = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.P_PImage);


                         //If mediaPlayer is paused.
                         if (IsPaused) {
                             P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp);
                             //If the song paused is same as the new song.
                             if (Current_Song == Old_Song) {

                                 mediaplayer.start();
                             }

                             //If the song Paused is not the new song.
                             else {
                                 if (mediaplayer != null) {
                                     mediaplayer.release();
                                     mediaplayer = null;
                                 }

                                 int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

                                 if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                                     mediaplayer = mediaplayer.create(SongsListActivity.this, song.getSong());
                                     Old_Song = song.getSong();
                                     NameD.setText(song.getNameOfSong());
                                     RateD.setText(song.getDeveloperRate());
                                     ImageD.setImageResource(song.getImage());
                                     mediaplayer.start();
                                     mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                             P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_48dp);
                                             IsPaused = true;
                                         }
                                     });
                                 }
                             }
                             IsPaused = false;

                         } else if (mediaplayer != null) {
                             //If mediaPlayer is already Playing a song.
                             if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
                                 P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_48dp);
                                 mediaplayer.pause();
                                 IVP_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
                                 IsPaused = true;
                             }
                         }

                         //If mediaPlayer is used for first time and if mediaPlayer is neither paused
                         else {

                             if (mediaplayer != null) {
                                 mediaplayer.release();
                                 mediaplayer = null;
                             }

                             int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

                             if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                                 mediaplayer = mediaplayer.create(SongsListActivity.this, song.getSong());
                                 Old_Song = song.getSong();
                                 NameD.setText(song.getNameOfSong());
                                 RateD.setText(song.getDeveloperRate());
                                 ImageD.setImageResource(song.getImage());
                                 mediaplayer.start();
                                 P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp);

                                 mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                         P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_48dp);
                                         IsPaused = true;
                                         P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp);

                                     }
                                 });
                             }
                         }

                     }

             }
            );
```

Here my app displays a list of songs using ListView and Adapter. The details of songs are stored in a arrayList(As You All Can See).When an item is clicked, it gets the position of that item, then refers to the corresponding element of the arrayList, gets the location of the corresponding song and then plays that song. What I want is that when an song is over, and the method onCompletion() is called, I want to increase to value of i(look in the 4th line of my code) by one and then start 
the corresponding song.

I want to do this using goto and label, but it is not working.(I put label in onItemClick at the very begening, to its very end and goto in the onCompletion. )

how can I use goto and label?

**Or is there any other EFFICIENT method to perform my task?**

PLEASE HELP ME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

So you have to create an index of all the songs in the playlists and then check

```
if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
```

For more you can check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Comment: I saw that page but i was not able to understand it properly. Can you tell me what can i do in the above code?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience but i am a nieve programmer

Comment: In your OnCompletion function, you are pausing your player instead try Songs song = Song.get(i+1);

Comment: Ok! But if I do that, will the mediaPlayer start playing automatically?

Comment: Did you try it? Do try and then ask

Comment: Ok! I tried it but it didn't help me.
Can you just tell me how can i use goto and label

Comment: It is really tough to tell like this, upload it on Github and let me know

Comment: I don't know how to upload on github. I have been using git and have made 3 to 4 commits, but i don't know how to upload it on github. I just know that we create a kind of remote, ................... And something like that.

Comment: I also have a github account but I am unable to use it.

Comment: Or wait for 1 day, i will learn it, upload the code on github and then let you know.

Comment: Wait, i don't think that uploading has been proper. I will do it properly later and then inform you.

Comment: yep. I added all my .java and .xml files on GitHub here:---                          https://github.com/JainHarshil1234567890/BestNarutoSongs

Comment: The activity in which I want you see is mainly SonglistActivity.java

Comment: By the way I have two Questions to you;- a)What is your age? and b)Do you watch Naruto?

Comment: 21, and yes I saw only one episode, as there were more than 500 episodes, my morale got hurt. Saw One Punch and My hero academy though. Really good.

Comment: Well, thus app which i am making contains the best songs(background tracks) of Naruto. And i am going to upload it on play store.

Comment: Everything is in red, so do one thing upload your entire app code along with all images and songs, dont worry I will not steal your project :) Or just push entire project to git hub from android studio

Comment: I think I will wait for a day or so and then i will let you know cuz i think I have started to figure out a solution to my question by myself.